# Manipulate pixels in QGraphcisPixmapItem

Tags: pyqt

I am using PyQt to build a small application for viewing images. When I click on the image I would like to alter the color of the pixels I have clicked:

Schematically my current code looks like this:

```
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView( scene )

image = QtGui.QImage( "image.png" )
pixmap = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem( QtGui.QPixMap.fromImage( image ))
scene.addItem( pixmap )
...
...
def mousePressEvent(self , event):
    print "Click on pixmap recorded - setting Pixel to red"
    image.setPixel( event.pos() , RED.rgb())
```

The code 'works' in the sense that the mousePressEvent() method is called, and the image.setPixel() method does not give any errors, but nothing happens on the screen. Any tips on how to get the updated pixels to be displayed?

Joakim

Answer (score 0):

To make changes appear, you need to reload image

```
self.image.setPixel(event.pos(), RED.rgb())
self.pixmap.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
```

But I'm not sure that it's a good way. If you don't need to save modified image, I'd add some circles (e.g. `addEllipse`) instead modifying pixels.

Also, don't forget to map window coordinates to image.